# Iterating through a list of string in python to return words with the same vowels

Tags: python, string, list, iteration

Your function word_list will take in a list of words. All words that have all the same vowels as the first word in the list should be returned in a list. The number of vowels does not matter, just merely that the words that you choose to include in that return list must contain the same vowels of the initial word. All words will be lowercase only to remove casing sensitivity. Vowels are simply a,e,i,o,u.

```
# These should all be True

def test_q3():
    print(word_list(["toe", "ocelot", "maniac"]) == ["toe", "ocelot"])

    print(word_list(["many", "carriage", "emit", "apricot", "aardvark"]) == ["many","aardvark"])

    print(word_list(["hoops", "chuff", "bot", "bottom"]) == ["hoops", "bot", "bottom"])
    
    print(word_list(["lab", "carriage", "emit", "apricot"]) == ["lab"]) # Notice here that none of the other words
    # had only a as a vowel (they all contained additional vowels)

test_q3()
```

I have tried counting vowels in each words to see that they exist and I have also tried creating a nested loop. Not sure which is best or how to fully implement a solution with no indexing errors

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. You mention some attempts to solve the problem. *Show us those attempts!* While we won't do your homework for you, we can help you troubleshoot the code you've already written. You may also want to reference [these](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) prior [discussions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) about homework questions on Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: It seems that extra copies of the same vowel are ok, so making a set seems like the natural solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since the task only cares about the presence of the vowels rather than their frequency, a `set` is appropriate here. You could write a helper function to extract the vowels from a word as a set, and then compare the results for each word. Something like:

```
def vowels(word):
  return set(word).intersection("aeiou")

def word_list(words):
  target = vowels(words[0])
  return [ word for word in words if vowels(word) == target ]
```

Comment: yea that is it, I was typing but the answer posted before mine!

Answer (score 0):

Using sets is a good way to approach this but I would recommend building a set of vowels and intersecting it directly with words rather that converting every word into a set.  set.intersection can work on an iterable that is not a set so it is not necessary to convert words to set before checking the intersections:

```
def word_list(L):
    WV = zip(L, map(set("aeiou").intersection,L))
    return L[:1]+[word for _,first in WV for word,other in WV if first==other]
```

*the way this works is by pairing each word with its set of vowels using zip().  The zip() function returns an iterator (WV) that we then use in a two level list comprehension.  The first level gets the first word/vowels pair form WV and the next level gets the rest (because it is reading the same iterator).*